# How to access Target Data for PRS analysis on GWAS Dataset

Tags: gwas

I am working on conducting a PRS analyses on a GWAS Dataset that deals with the alzheimer's disease. The data is split into cases(Participants with the disease) and controls(participants without the disease) dataset. After this, I have performed Quality Control on this dataset. To calculate PRS analysis, I would need to have a target dataset that consists of genotypes that are typically formatted as PLINK binary files. How would I access these binary files and how do I access the target dataset from UKbiobank?

Cases Dataset
[image]

Controls Dataset
[image]

I have tried to access the dataset from the following link but to no avail:
https://biobank.ndph.ox.ac.uk/showcase/label.cgi?id=263

For reference, the dataset must be in this format:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uhJR_3sn7RA8U5iYQbcmTp6vFdQiF4F2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this Stack and what we do here. You would be better off putting the required format in a code snippet box. You can do this by editing your question and using the preformatted text button on the tool bar - it looks like a pair of curly braces: {}. You might also find a better answer at our sister [Bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) site, but you should avoid cross-posting and request migration if you want to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by target dataset?

Answer (score 0):

The page you link says the following:

> Researchers must use the gfetch client (available from the Downloads section, instructions for use in Resource 668) to access the actual underlying genomic data or download them from the European Genome-phenome Archive (EGA).

Have you used the gfetch client? Do you still need to obtain the data or do you just need to convert it? It seems to be similar to the formats you've linked, e.g. BED/BIM/etc.